# How can i display most active people in order from active to less active

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I so i basically want to make a command that shows the most active people in the server in order, I know how to find the active people in the server at that time but not showing the most active:

```
@bot.command()
async def Most_Active(ctx):
    num=0
    await ctx.send("**Below're the most active users in the server**")
    for user in ctx.guild.members:
        if user.status == discord.Status.online:
            num += 1
            await ctx.send("\n{0}{1}".format(str(num),user.name))
            #This does acrually do what i want, It only tells the person online,
            #but i want to find the most active person (It's be better if it displays more in order
            # bu i don't care much about that)
```

Comment: Discord doesn't track those numbers (or if it does, they don't make them available to your bot).  You'll have to collect that data yourself.

Comment: You can collect who has sent the most messages send then display them in a sorted list or give them a role that shows they are the most active if they send a certain amount of messages within a time frame.

Comment: Which I'm not sure how to do, I guess that'll be a new question

Answer (score -1):

You are going to want some way to track that data, so how could you do that? Your best options is going to use a database. How could you integrate a database into your design? Easily, you can start out with something like SQLITE which is very easy to use and integrates easily with Python, you can log the amount of messages people send and then from that data see who is the 'most active'. So I suggest researching a database option that works for you, and that will provide you the easiest way of storing the data what you want.